# Как спрятать код в sublime text 3

Tags: css, sublime-text-3

На выходе проекта файл css обошёлся в ~2400 строк кода. Каждый раздел я закомментировал для понимания где что лежит. Я частенько пробегаюсь по css коду, где-то чищу, где-то добавляю что-то новое. Не удобно каждый раз пролистывать код по пять минут. Есть какой-нибудь плагин для sublime text 3, который поможет мне свернуть css код? У меня уже стоит встроенный плагин сворачивания (картинка снизу), но этого мне мало. Есть, например, плагины, которые позволяют выделить код, нажать комбинацию клавиш и код завернётся в обёртку, которую я смогу свернуть? [image: css стрелочка сворачивания блока]

Comment: Не мучайте себя, разделите большой файл на несколько маленьких

Comment: а (`Ctrl` + `-`) и (`Ctrl` + `+`) в SublimeText нет ?...(это не сарказм, я им не пользуюсь...просто искренне удивлен)

Comment: @МихаилРебров у меня уже стоит самый маленький размер, дальше некуда)